# Basis and dimension of Kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : R^3 → R^4$ be the linear transformation defined by:
$$T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (3x_1 − 4x_2 − x_3, x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3, 6x_1 − x_2 + 5x_3, 10x_2 + 10x_3)$$

Solution:
Determine the standard matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}3&-4&-1\\1&2&3\\6&-1&5\\0&10&10\end{bmatrix}$

Calculate the RREF of the standard matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Determining the kernel:

$\begin{bmatrix}3&-4&-1\\1&2&3\\6&-1&5\\0&10&10\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

=> $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Let $x_3 = t,\ t \in \mathbb{R}$

Then $x_1=-t,\ x_2 = -t,\ x_3 = t$

Therefore, a basis for Ker(T) is $\{(-1,-1,1)\}$ and dim(Ker(T)) = 1

I have been struggling with this topic so I would be really grateful if someone can please have a look and see if I did it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good.  Assuming your row reduction is correct.

Comment: thanks for checking!!